# Magento 2.4.6: How to create country attribute for custom registration form in

Tags: customer-account, custom-attributes, magento2.4.5, country-regions, magento2.4.6

How to create country attribute dropdown for customer registration form. I have added the country attribute in eav_attribute table using the following code:

vendor/module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'country_attribute', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Country',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => 'Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\Source\Country',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 10,
        'position' => 10,
        'system' => 0,
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'country_attribute')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();
}
}
```

added field in vendor/module/view/templates/registration.phtml

```
<div class="field required">
        <label for="country" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                <?php
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $yourAttribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('customer','country_attribute');
    if($yourAttribute->getSource()){
$options = $yourAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
   }

                ?>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="country_attribute" id="country_attribute" data-validate="{required:true}">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <?php
                foreach($options as $val){
                    if($val['value']!='')
                    echo '<option value="'.$val['value'].'">'.$val['label'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is working fine in Magento 2.4.5 but in Magento 2.4.6 it gives "Attribute country_attribute does not contain option with Id IN" error

[image]

Does anyone know how it work with Magento 2.4.6 ?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\Source\Country` with your own class and override the `getSpecificOptions` method.

The following example is a generic code which fetches all options. In your case you should fetch only the country options by id through the resource connection.

```php
/**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSpecificOptions($ids, $withEmpty = true)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions($withEmpty);

        if (!is_array($ids)) {
            $ids = explode(',', $ids);
        }

        $specificOptions = [];
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (in_array($option['value'], $ids)) {
                $specificOptions[] = $option;
            }
        }

        return $specificOptions;
    }
```